# sidecart not responding to ajax calls for dom manipulation using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a JavaScript code that contains functions triggering AJAX calls to a PHP file for handling. The issue revolves around a sidecart where users can adjust the quantity of items. Each item in the cart has buttons for increasing and decreasing the quantity in real-time. The buttons trigger JavaScript functions working with AJAX.

When a user clicks a button, they can choose to decrease or increase the quantity of a product. The expected behavior is that when the quantity of a certain product reaches zero, the HTML sidecart updates and removes the item. However, the remove function isn't working as intended. It fails to update the quantity in real-time, especially when the quantity is equal to 1, until a browser refresh is made. Additionally, it fails to delete items in the HTML when their quantity becomes zero unless multiple clicks are made and then a refresh occurs.

I understand that my code may be messy and lacks some best practices, as it's something I wrote earlier. Here's the first file that sends the request, which I believe is where the problem arises, named cart.js:

```
function initializeCounter(){

   var count=parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("qty"));
       // If qty is not present in session storage or it's NaN, retrieve it from the server-side PHP session variable
       if (isNaN(count)) {
         $.ajax({
             url: './Cart_Session.php', // Replace with the appropriate URL to fetch the quantity from PHP session
             method: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: {'action': 'init'},
             success: function(response) {
                 count = response.totalQuantity; // Assuming the totalQuantity is the quantity you want to retrieve
                 sessionStorage.setItem("qty", count);
                 updateCartCounter(count);
             },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 console.error('Failed to fetch quantity from server:', errorThrown);
             }
         });
     } else {
         updateCartCounter(count);
     }


    updateCartCounter(count);
   

   }
   
   window.onload = initializeCounter;
   

 function updateCartCounter(count){
   if(count>0){
   
   const cart = document.getElementById("cart");
   let qtySpan = cart.querySelector(".qty");
   
   if (!qtySpan) {
       qtySpan = document.createElement("span");
       qtySpan.className = "qty";
       cart.appendChild(qtySpan);
   }

   qtySpan.innerHTML = count;
   }
}






   function AddToCart(id,price){
      const quantity = 1;
      
      $.ajax({                                /* we will use Ajax to pass values from JS to PHP session storage */
         url: './Cart_Session.php',            /* js sessionstorage is not shared among php so we cannot use it as a shared place but we can pass values using Ajax with a Post request 
         and from that post request we will retrieve values and set it in session*/
         method: 'POST',                                 /* define the request header */
         datatype:"json",
         /* we get the data from the parameters above and put them in this keyed array  and then pass them in post request to the above php page*/
         data: {"action":"add","itemId": id, "price": price, "quantity": quantity},    /* action is the only variable that we set and don't retrieve from the parameters */  
         success: function(response) {
            try {
               var JSONresponse = JSON.parse(response);
               // Handle jsonResponse as an object
           } catch (e) {
               console.error('Error parsing JSON:', e);
           }
            
            sessionStorage.setItem("qty",JSONresponse['totalQuantity']);  /* set the js local storage to the totalquantity we got from php by checking array session */
            const cart=document.getElementById("cart");
            // Check if the qty span already exists
            let qtySpan = cart.querySelector(".qty");
   
            if (!qtySpan) {
               // If it doesn't exists, create it
               qtySpan = document.createElement("span");
               qtySpan.className = "qty";
               cart.appendChild(qtySpan);
             }
   
            qtySpan.innerHTML=parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("qty")) ;
            
            /* change the quantity inside the html sidebar */
            const qty=document.getElementById("qty-" + id);
            qty.innerText=JSONresponse['current_qty'];
            initializeCounter(); /* update the counter */
   
            alert('The item was added to your cart!');
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Failed !');
         }
     });
     
   
   
   
   
   }
   
   
   
   
   
  
   function RemoveFromCart(id){
      
      
      $.ajax({                                /* we will use Ajax to pass values from JS to PHP session storage */
         url: './Cart_Session.php',            /* js sessionstorage is not shared among php so we cannot use it as a shared place but we can pass values using Ajax with a Post request 
         and from that post request we will retrieve values and set it in session*/
         method: 'POST',                                 /* define the request header */
         /* we get the data from the parameters above and we only need an id since we are sure that the item exists*/
         data: {"action":"remove","itemId": id},    /* action is the only variable that we set and don't retrieve from the parameters */  
         success: function(response) {
            try {
               var JSONresponse = JSON.parse(response);
               // Handle jsonResponse as an object
           } catch (e) {
               console.error('Error parsing JSON:', e);
           }
   
            if(JSONresponse["flag"]==1){
               console.log("flagged");
               const product=document.getElementById("item-" + id);
               product.parentNode.removeChild(product);
   
            }
   
   
   
   
   
            
            sessionStorage.setItem("qty",JSONresponse["totalQuantity"]);  /* set the js session storage to the totalquantity we got from php by checking array session */
            const cart=document.getElementById("cart");
            // Check if the qty span already exists
            let qtySpan = cart.querySelector(".qty");
   
            if (!qtySpan) {
               // If it doesn't exists, create it
               qtySpan = document.createElement("span");
               qtySpan.className = "qty";
               cart.appendChild(qtySpan);
             }
   
            qtySpan.innerHTML=parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("qty")) ;
               if(JSONresponse["flag"]!=0){
              /* change the quantity inside the html sidebar */
               const qty=document.getElementById("qty-" + id);
               qty.innerText=JSONresponse['current_qty'];
               }
   
   
               initializeCounter(); /* update the counter */

            alert('The item was removed from your cart!');
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Failed !');
         }
     });
     
   
   
   
   
   }
```

now for the cart_session php that handles the requests

```
<?php
session_start(); // Start the PHP Session


$action=$_POST['action'];
$removeclass=0;

// Create cart in session if it doesn't exist
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart"])) {
  $_SESSION["cart"] = [];
}


 if ($action=="init"){
  if(isset($_SESSION["totalQuantity"])){
  
  
  $totalQuantity = $_SESSION["totalQuantity"];          /* intiliazing total quantity */

  }else {
    $totalQuantity=null;
  }


$responseArray=array(

  "totalQuantity"=>(int)$totalQuantity,


);

echo json_encode($responseArray);
exit;
 
}






if($action=="add"){
  $itemId = $_POST['itemId'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

  // Check if the item is in the cart and increase the quantity in that case
  if (array_key_exists($itemId, $_SESSION["cart"])) {
      $_SESSION['cart'][$itemId]['quantity']++;

  } else {
      // Structure the product data
      $item = ["id" => $itemId, "price" => $price,  "quantity" => $quantity ];        /* this is a keyed array */
      // Item is not in the cart, so add item to cart
      $_SESSION["cart"][$itemId] = $item;     /* now we will go the cart and this keyed array to the itemID unlike the default static array that is indexed according to the size , we are now making a custom index with product id */
  }
  
  $_SESSION['totalQuantity']++;



}  

if($action=="remove"){
  $itemId=$_POST['itemId'];

      // Check if the item exists in the cart
  if (array_key_exists($itemId, $_SESSION["cart"])) {
       // Only decrease quantity if it's greater than 0
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$itemId]['quantity'] > 0) {
          $_SESSION['cart'][$itemId]['quantity']--;
          $_SESSION['totalQuantity']--;

        
        }

        if($_SESSION['cart'][$itemId]['quantity'] <= 0) {
          unset($_SESSION["cart"][$itemId]);
          $removeclass=1;
      
      }
            

  }

}







$totalQuantity = $_SESSION["totalQuantity"];          /* intiliazing total quantity */


if (isset($_POST['itemId'])) {
  $itemId = $_POST['itemId'];
} else {
  $itemId = null;
}



$responseArray=array(

  "totalQuantity"=>(int)$totalQuantity,
  "current_qty"=>(int) $_SESSION['cart'][$itemId]['quantity']  ,
  "flag"=>(int)$removeclass,

);

echo json_encode($responseArray);      /* echo is the official way to return the request back to ajax now with the totalquantity variable */


exit;


/* echo 'Product added to cart!';
 */?>
```

possible causes of concern that appear in the browser dev console

1. sometimes when i click on the decrease button i get

   ````
       at Object.success (cart.js:128:28)
       at c (jquery.min.js:2:25304)
       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:26053)
       at l (jquery.min.js:2:77782)
       at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:80265)
   success @ cart.js:128
   c @ jquery.min.js:2
   fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
   l @ jquery.min.js:2
   (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
   load (async)
   send @ jquery.min.js:2
   ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
   RemoveFromCart @ cart.js:114
   onclick @ Home.php:112 ```
   ````

2)i also sometimes get this when the quantity is 1 and it fails to be updated to get removed:

```
cart.js:125 Error parsing JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br />
 <b>"... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (cart.js:122:40)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2:25304)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:26053)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2:77782)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:80265)
success @ cart.js:125
```